# How to install debian 12 with full disk (boot too) luks2 encryption grub2, lvm UEFI?

Tags: debian, grub2, uefi, encryption, luks

This is a laptop with an SSD. The debian installer defaults are for luks2. Using these breaks the install at the grub part, as the latest grub version doesn't support argon2id PBKDFs. argon2id is supposed to be a lot better than the luks1 way, however the latter should work out of the box. (Other than grub, debian installed without problem.)

I have followed a couple of [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8N9jKWm-cKY) to install debian from a live usb. (debian-live-12.1.0-amd64-lxqt.iso)

My disk setup was to have a 1GB EFI partition. (This may be too big...) An encrypted partition named crypt, an LVM inside it (which I probably didn't need actually) and in the LVM, a volume group vg-1 and in that a vg1-debian ext4 root partition and a vg1-store ext4 partition for my data.

```
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1             259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1         259:1    0     1G  0 part  /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2         259:2    0   215G  0 part 
  └─nvme0n1p2_crypt 253:0    0   215G  0 crypt
    ├─vg1-debian    253:1    0  46.6G  0 lvm   /
    └─vg1-store     253:2    0 167.6G  0 lvm   /media/user/store
```

Comment: Split your post to Question and Answer. This is the way this site work!

Answer (score 2):

---

**DISCLAIMERS:**
Back up your data!
Having another computer helps!
This takes some time even if everything works correctly on the first try!
You have to unlock the encrypted drive TWICE on boot.
I have only tried the UEFI mode install.

---

So, the solution to this problem is to use a live usb, create the partitions, install debian, skipping grub, boot with the live usb, chroot into the new install and compile and install the patched grub.
Because this is so damn tedious, I have made a script for it.
I used the name gil_install.sh.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

script_rel_path="/home/tempuser"
script_full_path="$script_rel_path/"$(basename "$0")

# choose which part of the script should run based on cli argument
# no argument case
if [ -z "$1" ] ; then

    # assuming installed debian 12 system is mounted to /mnt
    mkdir "/mnt$script_rel_path"
    cp "$0" "/mnt$script_full_path"

    # mount essentials for chroot
    # https://wiki.debian.org/chroot
    mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev/
    mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
    mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
    mount --bind /sys  /mnt/sys
    mount --bind /run  /mnt/run

    # chroot and start the next part of this script from within the chroot
    # couldn't get this part to work right
    #chroot /mnt /bin/bash -i "$script_full_path 1"
    
    echo "After chroot, enter command: cd $script_rel_path; bash $script_full_path 1"
    chroot /mnt
fi

if [ "$1" == 1 ] ; then

    echo "Installing build packages"
    apt install -y gnulib libdevmapper-dev libfreetype-dev gettext autogen git bison help2man texinfo efibootmgr libisoburn1 libisoburn-dev mtools pkg-config m4 libtool automake autoconf flex fuse3 libfuse3-dev gawk

    # mawk gives make error, so using gawk
    mv /usr/bin/mawk /usr/bin/mawk_bu
    ln -s /usr/bin/gawk /usr/bin/mawk

    # git clone needed repos
    git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/grub.git
    cd grub
    git clone https://git.savannah.nongnu.org/git/grub-extras.git
    git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/grub-improved-luks2-git.git
    git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/gnulib.git

    cp "$0" "./"$(basename "$0")

    /bin/bash -i $(basename "$0") 2
fi

if [ "$1" == 2 ] ; then

    echo "Compiling grub"

    # This part is copied from grub-improved-luks2-git/PKGBUILD
    # It patches grub and compiles and installes it

    patch -Np1 -i ./grub-improved-luks2-git/add-GRUB_COLOR_variables.patch

    # Patch grub-mkconfig to detect Arch Linux initramfs images.
    patch -Np1 -i ./grub-improved-luks2-git/detect-archlinux-initramfs.patch

    # argon2
    patch -Np1 -i ./grub-improved-luks2-git/argon_1.patch
    patch -Np1 -i ./grub-improved-luks2-git/argon_2.patch
    patch -Np1 -i ./grub-improved-luks2-git/argon_3.patch
    patch -Np1 -i ./grub-improved-luks2-git/argon_4.patch
    patch -Np1 -i ./grub-improved-luks2-git/argon_5.patch

    # make grub-install work with luks2
    patch -Np1 -i ./grub-improved-luks2-git/grub-install_luks2.patch

    # Fix DejaVuSans.ttf location so that grub-mkfont can create *.pf2 files for starfield theme.
    sed 's|/usr/share/fonts/dejavu|/usr/share/fonts/dejavu /usr/share/fonts/TTF|g' -i "configure.ac"

    # Modify grub-mkconfig behaviour to silence warnings FS#36275
    sed 's| ro | rw |g' -i "util/grub.d/10_linux.in"

    # Modify grub-mkconfig behaviour so automatically generated entries read 'Arch Linux' FS#33393
    sed 's|GNU/Linux|Linux|' -i "util/grub.d/10_linux.in"

    # Pull in latest language files
    #[ ! -z "$GRUB_ENABLE_NLS" ] && ./linguas.sh

    # Remove lua module from grub-extras as it is incompatible with changes to grub_file_open
    # http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/commit/?id=ca0a4f689a02c2c5a5e385f874aaaa38e151564e
    rm -rf ./grub-extras/lua

    export GRUB_CONTRIB=./grub-extras
    export GNULIB_SRCDIR=./gnulib
    CFLAGS=${CFLAGS/-fno-plt}

    ./bootstrap
    mkdir ./build_x86_64-efi
    cd ./build_x86_64-efi
    ../configure --with-platform=efi --target=x86_64 --prefix="/usr" --sbindir="/usr/bin" --sysconfdir="/etc" --enable-boot-time --enable-cache-stats --enable-device-mapper --enable-grub-mkfont --enable-grub-mount --enable-mm-debug --disable-silent-rules --disable-werror  CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -O2"
    make

    cd ..
    # now we should be in /home/tempuser/grub (on the mounted filesystem)
    /bin/bash -i $(basename "$0") 3
fi

if [ "$1" == 3 ] ; then

    echo "Installing grub"
#    exit

    cd ./build_x86_64-efi
    make DESTDIR=/ bashcompletiondir=/usr/share/bash-completion/completions install
    install -D -m0644 ../grub-improved-luks2-git/grub.default /etc/default/grub

fi
```

Once you have the live usb running, open the encrypted volume (change this!)

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p2 crypt
```

Mount it to /mnt (change partition name!)

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/vg1-debian /mnt
```

Mount the efi partition to /mnt/boot/efi (change partition name!)

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/boot/efi
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi
```

Opt: Make a backup of the debian grub config
(or to use this one comment out the appropriate line in my script)
(The one in the patch is for Arch, but works.)
(Maybe the base debian version is better, but I haven't tried that.)

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub_bu
```

Download my script and start it:

```
sudo bash gil_install.sh
```

NOTE that after entering chroot, you will have to copy and execute a command manually.
(It is in the script. / Printed out to the terminal.)
After that, the script should run, make and install the patched grub.
You may continue the script from various points using cli arguments.
(See inside script.)
NOTE that the script copies itself across multiple directories, so be careful which one you edit or execute.

See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#LUKS2
Inside chroot:
Enable cryptodisk in grub
(Uncomment GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y line)
(Also change Arch to Debian...)

```
nano /etc/default/grub
```

Use the grub-mkconfig tool to generate /boot/grub/grub.cfg:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Install grub to efi partition

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=GRUB
```

Create /boot/grub/grub-pre.cfg

```
nano /boot/grub/grub-pre.cfg
```

```
set crypto_uuid=3b411d89-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx  
cryptomount -u $crypto_uuid
set root=lvm/vg1-debian
set prefix=($root)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

Make efi image:

```
grub-mkimage -p /boot/grub -O x86_64-efi -c /boot/grub/grub-pre.cfg -o /tmp/grubx64.efi luks2 part_gpt cryptodisk gcry_rijndael argon2 gcry_sha256 ext2 lvm
```

Copy to ESP:

```
install -v /tmp/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/GRUB/grubx64.efi
```

Add efi entry:

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/nvme0n1 -p 1 -L "debian" -l "\EFI\GRUB\grubx64.efi"
```

After all this and some efibootmgr 'magic' I could boot into my brand new debian 12 install.
Hope this helps.
I probably won't be around to maintain this, sorry.
(I have wasted too much time on it as it is.)